# How to call a method after successfully storing data in state in react

Tags: reactjs

```
    import React from 'react';
    import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
    import { lookup } from 'dns';

    export default class Pagination extends React.Component {

        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                contacts : [],
                per:5,
                page:1,
                totalPages:null,
                country:null
            }

        }


        componentDidMount(){
            document.getElementById('us').click()
        }

        handleCountry = (country=null) => {
            const {per, page, contacts} = this.state;
            if (country === null){
                country = 'United States'
            }
            const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/?limit=${per}&page=${page}&country=${country}`
            fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(
                json => {
                    this.setState({
                        contacts:json.data
                    })
                }
            )
        }

        loadMore = (country) => {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                page: prevState.page + 1,
            }), this.loadContacts(country))
        }

        handleCountry = (event) => {
            this.setState({
                country:event.target.value,
                page:1
            })
            this.loadContacts(event.target.value);    
        }

        render(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>

                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" id="us" name="country" value="United States" onClick={this.handleCountry} />United States
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" id="india" name="country" value="India" onClick={this.handleCountry} />India
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" id="canada" name="country" value="Canada" onClick={this.handleCountry} />Canada
                        </label>

                    </div>
                    <ul className="contacts" style={{ width:'300px' }}>
                        {
                            this.state.contacts.map(contact => 
                                <li key={contact.id} style={{ padding:'5px 5px 5px 5px' }}>
                                    <div className="contact" style={{ background:'#0099ff', padding:'10px', color:'white' }}>
                                        <div>{ contact.id }</div>
                                        <div>{ contact.country }</div>
                                        <div>{ contact.name }</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            )
                        }
                    </ul>
                    <button onClick={() => this.loadMore(this.state.country)}>Load More</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Here I am stuck with a issue in reactjs.

When i am clicking any radio button its calling **handleCountry()** method and passing event.
Then i am storing the event in state. Then calling **handleCountry()** function to fetch api.

But in **handleCountry()** method first **loadContacts()** method calling then it storing the data in state.

So I am not getting correct result.

I can i make call **loadContacts()** after successfully storing data in **state** inside **loadContacts()** method.

Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use callback method with setState to achieve the expected result, it will be executed after successful state update.

Like this:

```
handleCountry = (event) => {
  let { value } = event.target;
  this.setState({
    country: value,
    page:1
  }, () => {
    this.loadContacts(value);
  })
}
```

Check [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#setstate) for more detail about setState.

Comment: Thanks bro. That work for me  but , for the first time after clicking 2 times Load More button api is calling

Comment: put console.log in loadMore and loadContacts method and check whether getting called or not.

Comment: Okk. Let me dubug

Comment: Yes both methods are calling .

Comment: Thanks anyway. Can fix the issue after try